# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, https

I am trying to setup the SightMax livechat using the https, but when request the url below

https://livechat.domain.com/Live-Chat/agentinterfacejson.svc/ssl/chat/RequestSurvey

It return this error

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http].

Have tried research around but still cannot get it right,
below is my web.config
The IIS already setup with binding to the https.

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="jsonpBinding">
            <jsonpMessageEncoding/>
            <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="jsonpBindingSsl">
            <jsonpMessageEncoding/>
            <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="52428800" maxStringContentLength="52428800" maxArrayLength="52428800"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="sslJsonBinding">
            <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="jsonpBindingSsl">
            <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
     </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonBehavior" name="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJson">
        <endpoint address="chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" name="jsonChat" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat"/>
        <endpoint address="site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" name="jsonSite" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite"/>
                <!--Uncomment in order to enable SSL-->
          <endpoint address="ssl/chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslJsonBinding"
          name="jsonChatSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat" />
        <endpoint address="ssl/site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslJsonBinding"
          name="jsonSiteSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite" />
     </service>

    <service behaviorConfiguration="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonpBehavior" name="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonp">
        <endpoint address="chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" name="jsonpChat" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat"/>
        <endpoint address="site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" name="jsonpSite" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite"/>
        <!--Uncomment in order to enable SSL-->
        <endpoint address="ssl/chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBindingSsl"
          name="jsonChatSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat" />
        <endpoint address="ssl/site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBindingSsl"
          name="jsonSiteSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Any ideas on this ? Thanks

I have tried to put the base address on each service, but still no luck.

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonBehavior" name="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJson">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://livechat.domain.com/Live-Chat/agentinterfacejson.svc/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" name="jsonChat" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat"/>
        <endpoint address="site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" name="jsonSite" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite"/>
        <!--Uncomment in order to enable SSL-->
            <endpoint address="ssl/chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior"binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslJsonBinding"name="jsonChatSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat" />
            <endpoint address="ssl/site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior"binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sslJsonBinding"name="jsonSiteSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonpBehavior" name="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterfaceService.AgentInterfaceJsonp">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://livechat.domain.com/Live-Chat/agentinterfacejson.svc/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" name="jsonpChat" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat"/>
        <endpoint address="site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" name="jsonpSite" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite"/>
        <!--Uncomment in order to enable SSL-->
            <endpoint address="ssl/chat" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior"binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBindingSsl"name="jsonChatSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Chat.Visitor.IRemotedVisitorChat" />
            <endpoint address="ssl/site" behaviorConfiguration="jsonpEndpointBehavior"binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBindingSsl"name="jsonSiteSsl" contract="SmartMax.SightMax.Website.IRemotedVisitorWebsite" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a BaseAddress and your endpoint address are relative.

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="https://livechat.domain.com/Livechat/agentinterfacejson.svc" />
</baseAddresses>
```

[WCF Service Host settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789018.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply, and where should I put the baseaddress ? and I need to put two base address (http and https) ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to add the base addresses but still not luck.